# Insert missing values (products) from table A to table B while also using data from table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is probably a common sense way of going about this, but I haven't figured it out this morning.

I've got 2 tables:

**Stores** with columns Address and Product

**Inventory** with columns Timestamp, Address and Product

The stores table lists out stores by address and the products that should be at that store, for example:

Walmart 12 Fake St | Product #708034
Walmart 12 Fake St | Product #809587

The Inventory table lists out stores by time stamp (of scan) address and the products that were **actually there** (scanned by a sales rep), for example:

November 11 | Walmart 12 Fake St | Product #708034

As you can see there is a "missing" product in the Inventory table, #809587. My goal here is to insert any products from the **Stores** table that are missing in the **Inventory** table tagging them as missing for reporting purposes.

Where I'm getting stuck is how to do this while also including the time stamp from the **Inventory** table for that day, since I need the time stamp to be the same on the artificially inserted record as the other actual records that were scanned.

I've done a full outer join between Stores and Inventory where the Product is NULL in the Inventory table to find missing products, but from there I'm stuck on what to do with the time stamp.

Comment: Can you add a little more details to your question, i.e. 1) once you are inserting a store with the product and if the product is missing you want to insert it in the inventory table with current time stamp, is this correct.

Comment: We are a little stuck too as we have no idea what you want to do with this timestamp. Be careful using the name time stamp because in sql server it is a datatype that has nothing to do with dates or times. ScanTime might be a better name. It seems you have some pretty serious normalization issues here. Why does your Stores table have a column for product? You have to repeat all the information for each store for every single product. You should have at least 3 tables here. Stores, Product, Inventory

Comment: If you really want some help this is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/